# Inject adapter into activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, dependency-injection, guice, roboguice

I'm learning how to use RoboGuice (and Dependency Injection in general). The problem I have is I want to inject custom FragmentPagerAdapter into activity, but I need to pass FragmentManager somehow. Is there a way to do that? In documentation they present a way to pass context, but I need to pass FragmentManager - do I need to do that the same way?

Answer (score 1):

For Dagger:

Define a binding for the `FragmentManager` in an **Activity-specific subgraph** using `Activity.getFragmentManager()`.  Then inject the `FragmentManager` into the `FragmentPagerAdapter`, and inject the `FragmentPagerAdapter` into the `Activity`.

```
public class ActivityModule {

  private final Activity activity;

  public ActivityModule(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
  }

  @Provides
  public Activity getActivity() {
    return activity;
  }

  @Provides
  FragmentManager provideFragmentManager(Activity activity) {
    return activity.getFragmentManager();
  }
}
```

Comment: This question isn't about Dagger is it?

Comment: I was hoping there were equivalent concepts in RoboGuice; I only have experience with Dagger.   Regardless of your DI framework, the solution is to inject the FragmentPagerAdapter into the Activity, and the FragmentManager into the FragmentPagerAdapter, and the binding for that FragmentManager should be scoped to the Activity (i.e. activity specific subgraph).

Comment: @jimmyorr I switched to Dagger to check it out, but using your solution I still get Error:(24, 8) Gradle: error: No injectable members on android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by com.example.app.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter for com.example.app.AppModule

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can inject the `Activity` directly.  Then you should be able to just call `activity.getFragmentManager()`.  Or if you're using the support library, `((FragmentActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: So how do I do that?  Do I pass Provider<Activity> as an argument to the constructor of my adapter and it gets automatically instantiated?

Comment: However you were injecting a `Context`, do the sane for `Activity`.